# How to remove all parameters' values from query

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have a number of query strings looks like `View.aspx?type=a&boo=bar&i=1`

How to remove all parameters' values so it would become `View.aspx?type=&boo=&i=`

For each string set of parameters there is it's own combination of parameters, 2-3 in number.

**Edit:** How to remove all parameters except specific set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all parameters

```
Regex.Replace(source, "=.+?(&|$)", "=$1")
```

To skip parameters "archive" and "boo":

```
Regex.Replace(source, "(?<![?&]archive|[?&]boo)=.+?(&|$)", "=$1",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible to skip specific set of parameters and their values appropriately? I.e. View.aspx?type=a&boo=bar&i=1&archive=true to View.aspx?type=a&boo=&i=&archive=true

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this inside that page? Why not forward the page to itself without parameters? Maybe I am missing the point. Care to explain a little more?

Comment: I'm writing my own SiteMapProvider using overriding of System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode and nodes in my sitemap for being dynamic has only params' names not values

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Uri`, or `System.UriBuilder`

Comment: How can i use it for my task?

Comment: Also I need to say that System.Uri is castrated class that can do nothing with query

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "castrated class". System.Uri is an immutable class (like System.String). To manipulate Uris, you need to use UriBuilder.

On reading your question again, I think there is no "canned" way of doing this. new Uri("http://foo/bar.aspx?foo=bar&goo=jar").AbsolutePath will give you back "/bar.aspx" but it does not accomplish what you want. Youu can of course get the Query property, split it using String.Split() and then manipulate it.